# personalize twitter button to share content (get rid of the blue button)

Tags: html, twitter

I have a website with a icon set to share on social networks.

I have problems with the Twitter one and Facebook too.

Actual code for the icons looks like this

```
<li class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.3s">
    <a href="#"><i class="ion-social-facebook"></i></a>
</li>                           
<li class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
    <a href="#"><i class="ion-social-twitter"></i></a>
</li>
```

In the case of Facebook (working) takes you to your wall to post the link of the website (I would like to include a picture) without positive results so far.

This is the code included for facebook:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://website.com/index.html" target="_blank"><i class="ion-social-facebook">
```

And this 2 meta properties in the header:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.website.com/images/tricki.png"/>
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://www.website/images/tricki.png" />
```

In the case of Twitter, this is the code:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="www.website.com/index.html" data-text="Check out this new game!!" data-hashtags="trickigame">
<i class="ion-social-twitter"></i></a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
```

If I delete the class="twitter-share-button" it deletes the horrible blue button from twitter and keeps mine. but if I click on it will take me to twitter but with a blank area, and If I insert back that class="twitter-share-button" it shows the twitter blue button and if you click this it takes you to twitter but with a pre-written content by myself (with hashtags etc etc). Why this is not working? any help?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=twitter+share+via+url

Answer (score 0):

1. To get the image in facebook share remove secure_url from meta tag, use below tag:

   ```
   <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.your-domain.com/your-page.html" />
   <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
   <meta property="og:title" content="Your Website Title" />
   <meta property="og:description" content="Your description" />
   <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.your-domain.com/path/image.jpg" />
   ```
2. Twitter share button can not work with "twitter-share-button" as twitter use this class to discover the shared content. you can only change the size of the button. By using below code

   ```
   <a class="twitter-share-button" href="https://twitter.com/share" data-size="large" data-text="custom share text" data-url="https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button" data-hashtags="example,demo" data-via="twitterdev" data-related="twitterapi,twitter">Tweet</a>
   ```

refer this link https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button/parameters#button
 I hope it will solve your problem